# Dynamic range in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, data-entry

I have `column A` of `sheet 1` where there is lot of time data.

In `sheet 2` I wanted to count the data if some condition is matching based in index I wanted to give. I'm doing it in `Sheet 2`.

For e.g. sometimes I need to count from `3rd` cell to `20th` cell of `Col A` of `Sheet 1` like given below

```
COUNTIF(sheet1!A3:A20, "some condition")
```

and sometimes I wanted to count from `7th` cell to `91st` cell of `Col A` of `Sheet 1` like

```
COUNTIF(sheet1!A7:A91, "some other condition")
```

Now, my problem has evolved and I have more cols in `Sheet 1` (like `Col B`, `Col C`, etc.). As a result it becomes tedious task to change range index for each of them).

WHat I wanted is - if there is a way to put index values (`startIndex` and `endIndex`) in `sheet 2`.
So what I'm trying to do is to reference `startIndex`, `endIndex` and `columnName` to caluclate the count. And it is giving me error (formula parse error).

[image]

Comment: Google Sheets or Excel? You tagged both - which one?

Comment: google sheets, sorry for confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=countif(indirect("Sheet1!"&B3&B1&":"&B3&B2),">20")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked, I was missing "&".